# how to configure a custom amazon EMR bootstrap action in code

Tags: elastic-map-reduce

I am trying to configure a bootstrap action in code. I am able to successfully run my job with Bootstrap action using the UI in amazon so I know my bootstrap action is working.

Also without the bootstrap action I am able to successfully invoke my hadoop job in code but when I add the bootstrap action to the EMR job it fails. and no debug logs get generated either.

I think I the Name for the bootstrap action has to be a fixed name for custom action and I do not know what it should be. This is what I have in code:

```
ScriptBootstrapActionConfig bootstrapActionScript = new ScriptBootstrapActionConfig() .WithPath("s3n://deverivaeast/Mangal_Hadoop/Scripts/UniqueUsers/UploadDeliveryToCampaignMap.sh");
BootstrapActionConfig bootstrapAction = new BootstrapActionConfig() .WithName("Custom Action") // WHAT SHOULD BE THE NAME .WithScriptBootstrapAction(bootstrapActionScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a non issue. I had the path to my mapper and reducer wrong.
The bootstrap action works fine